# MailApp's sender name functionality stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I'm using for work, and yesterday (between 3:53pm and 4:34pm PDT, October 25, 2012) the ['name' argument of MailApp.sendEmail's advanced arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp) suddenly stopped working.  Now, whether the argument is declared or not, the email that gets sent out just appears to come from "xyz@example.com" and not "John Doe 'xyz@example.com'", for instance.

[Issue 2004](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2004) in google-apps-script-issues was created a little while ago, and I starred it already.  I was just wondering if anybody knows when this functionality might be working again.  I'm hoping it was not permanently disabled, for security reasons, perhaps.  It is very important to me.

Here is a sample code that replicates the issue.  The email that gets sent to whoever@example.com will not have "Custom name" in the from field:

```
function myFunction() {
var fromName =  "Custom name";
  var optAdvancedArgs = {name: fromName};
  MailApp.sendEmail("whoever@example.com", "Subject", "body", optAdvancedArgs);
}
```

Comment: Only a Google employee can answer this. This question better fits the the issue you've already linked.

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 2004:  MailApp.sendEmail Advanced Argument "name" not working](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2004#c28)  was reported "fixed" Nov 13, 2012.